# Winforms ComboBox - Set value directly

Tags: winforms, combobox

I figured out how to add events to my combobox in the datagrid view:

```
    private void dataGridViewCaseObjects_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        var combo = e.Control as ComboBox;
        if (combo != null)
        {
            combo.SelectedIndexChanged -= ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged;
            combo.SelectedIndexChanged += ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged;
        }
    }

    private void ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Actually commit the selected string to combobox 
    }
```

How do I force the commit to the combobox from this point?

Comment: Force the commit? If you check the value of your combobox in the indexchanged method you'll get the selected string.

Comment: Describe what you want clearly. Do you want the selected text be sent to somewhere else , e.g another control?